# Converging distribution of sum of square of normal random variables divided by the square root of number of random variables

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics

How can I find the converging distribution of $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i^2,~Y_i \overset{\textrm{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$? My first thought was CLT but I do not think it works because of the division by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Have you really compared the form with CLT carefully?

Comment: The distribution doesn't converge, so your question doesn't have an answer. On the other hand, the distribution is known exactly for any $n$, so why would you need to use asymptotics?